# How do I centre a tabularx table?

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have a pretty big data table for an organic chemistry lab and trying to make it look nice as possible.  However, not all headers are centred.

```
% Organic Chemistry II Lab Template

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames,table,xcdraw,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadings,patterns}
\pagenumbering{roman}


\begin{document} 
\thispagestyle{empty}               % Remove page numbering on this page
\titleGP % This command includes the title page
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{J. Weinraub}
\lhead{Experiment XXIV: Aldehydes and Ketones}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\section*{Introduction}

\section*{Results}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|*{3}{X|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Lab Practicum Organic Chemistry II}                                                                                                                                                                          \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Compound}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}    {\textbf{Solubility}}                                                        &     \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Density}}                                                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                  & \textit{\textbf{Observation}}                       & \textit{\textbf{Conclusion}}                  & \textit{\textbf{Observation}}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Conclusion}}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Acetone}                        & Miscible                                            & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000}                      & Miscible                          & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000}                          \\ \hline
\textbf{1-Butanal}                      & $\sim$8-9 drops                                     & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000}                      & Floats                            & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000}                          \\ \hline
\textbf{2-Butanone}                     & \textless10 drops                                   & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000}                      & Floats                            & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000}                          \\ \hline
\textbf{Cyclohexanone}                  & 6 drops                                             & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000}                      & Sinks                             & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000}                          \\ \hline
\textbf{Benzaladehyde}                  & \textgreater10 drops                                & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000}                      & Sinks                             & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000}                          \\ \hline
\textbf{Unknown \#6}                    & 4-5 drops                                           & Boils at 75                                   & Floats                            &                                                   \\ \hline
                                        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{2,4-    Dinitrophenylhydrazone}}                                        &     \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Semicarbazones}}                                          \\ \hline
\textbf{Acetone}                        & Solid                                               & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000}                      & ---                               & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000}                          \\ \hline
\textbf{Benzaldehyde}                   & Solid                                               & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000}                      & Slight ppt                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000}                          \\ \hline
\textbf{Unknown \#6}                    & Solid                                               &                                               & Precipitated                      &                                                   \\ \hline
                                        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}    {\textbf{Chromic Acid Oxidation}}                                            &     \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Tollen's Test}}                                           \\ \hline
\textbf{Acetone}                        & Positive                                            & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000}                      & Negative                          & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000}                          \\ \hline
\textbf{1-Propanal}                     & Negative                                            & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000}                      & Positive                          & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000}                          \\ \hline
\textbf{Benzaldehyde}                   & Positive                                            & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000}                      & Positive                          & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000}                          \\ \hline
\textbf{Glucose}                        & \cellcolor[HTML]    {C0C0C0}\textbf{Skip This Test} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000}                          & Positive                      & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000}                              \\ \hline
\textbf{Unknown \#6}                    & Positive                                            &                                               & Positve                           &                                                   \\ \hline
                                        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}    {\textbf{Iodoform Test}}                                                     &     \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}         &                                                       \\ \hline
\textbf{Acetone}                        & Precipitated                                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}             &                                                   \\ \hline
\textbf{Ethanol}                        & No Reaction                                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}             &                                                   \\ \hline
\textbf{Cyclohexanone}                  & No Reaction                                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}             &                                                   \\ \hline
\textbf{Unknown \#6}                    & No Reaction                                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}             &                                                   \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: My table how it appears now]

And I like all fields to be centred or maybe formatted better than I have it now if you think that is the right thing to do.

Comment: I'd recommend following the `booktabs` guidelines, using print-quality horizontal rules and eliminating the vertical rules. To centre a single cell, you can use `\centering`. To centre an `X` column, you can use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}X` in the table specification in place of `X`. Or you can define a new column type for this if you expect to use it repeatedly.

Comment: Personally, I would not centre some of the stuff you are currently centring, rather than the other way round. And the heavy black rectangles are very distracting visually. They catch the eye rather than cells with actual content, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: The reason for tabularx is I like the full width table size but as originally the table was blank for handwritten data prior to the experiment, I suppose now it isn't an entirely an issue.  I agree vertical rules are ugly and just used Excel as a "guide" to make it.

Comment: My suggestions are entirely compatible with `tabularx`. I did not suggest dropping it.

Comment: @cfr I would like to use a lightweight slashes but can never figure out how to do that in Tex.

Comment: Your example is not very minimal. Surely you don't need `graphicx` or `tikz` for this!

Comment: I didn't copy and paste the entire document though I have gotten in a bind when I stripped out too many items from the preamble, so I kept it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this will at least provide some ideas. I'm not sure what the final contents of the table will look like but I assume some empty cells will end up filled which will change things. At least, that's what I assume here.

This is an abuse of both `makecells` and `booktabs`. `\midrule` is not meant to be used like this. Neither is `\diaghead`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}% bold tabular headers
\renewcommand\theadalign{lcc}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}% booktabs rules already add vertical spacing
\newcommand\tsubheadfont{\itshape\bfseries}
\newcommand*\tsubhead[1]{\tsubheadfont #1}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \caption{Lab Practicum Organic Chemistry II}\label{tab:pracII}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries\arraybackslash}l*{4}{C}}
    \toprule
    \thead{Compound} & \multicolumn{2}{c} {\theadfont Solubility} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\theadfont Density} \\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
     & \tsubhead{Observation} & \tsubhead{Conclusion} & \tsubhead{Observation} & \tsubhead{Conclusion} \\
    \midrule
    Acetone & Miscible & \multirow{5}*{\diaghead(2,1){\hskip\hsize}{}{}} & Miscible & \multirow{5}*{\diaghead(2,1){\hskip\hsize}{}{}} \\
    1-Butanal & $\sim$8-9 drops &  & Floats &  \\
    2-Butanone & \textless10 drops &  & Floats &  \\
    Cyclohexanone & 6 drops &  & Sinks &  \\
    Benzaladehyde & \textgreater10 drops &  & Sinks &  \\
    Unknown \#6 & 4-5 drops & Boils at 75 & Floats & \\
    \midrule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\theadfont {2,4- Dinitrophenylhydrazone}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\theadfont {Semicarbazones}} \\
    \midrule
    Acetone & Solid & \multirow{3}*{\diaghead(4,1){\hskip\hsize}{}{}} & --- & \multirow{2}*{\diaghead(5,1){\hskip\hsize}{}{}} \\
    Benzaldehyde & Solid &  & Slight ppt & \\
    Unknown \#6 & Solid & & Precipitated & \\
    \midrule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c} {\theadfont Chromic Acid Oxidation} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\theadfont {Tollen's Test}} \\
    \midrule
    Acetone & Positive & \multirow{4}*{\diaghead(3,1){\hskip\hsize}{}{}} & Negative & \multirow{4}*{\diaghead(3,1){\hskip\hsize}{}{}} \\
    1-Propanal & Negative &  & Positive &  \\
    Benzaldehyde & Positive &  & Positive &  \\
    Glucose & \textbf{Skip This Test} &  & Positive &  \\
    Unknown \#6 & Positive & & Positve & \\
    \midrule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c} {\theadfont {Iodoform Test}} &  & \\
    \midrule
    Acetone & Precipitated & \multirow{3}*{\diaghead(4,1){\hskip\hsize}{}{}} &  & \\
    Ethanol & No Reaction &  & & \\
    Cyclohexanone & No Reaction &  & & \\
    Unknown \#6 & No Reaction &  &  & \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This produces

[image: hackish tabular]

However, I would probably do something simpler such as

[image: simpler tabular]

```
\begin{table}
  \caption{Lab Practicum Organic Chemistry II}\label{tab:pracII}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries\arraybackslash}l*{4}{C}}
    \toprule
    \thead{Compound} & \multicolumn{2}{c} {\theadfont Solubility} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\theadfont Density} \\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
     & \tsubhead{Observation} & \tsubhead{Conclusion} & \tsubhead{Observation} & \tsubhead{Conclusion} \\
    \midrule
    Acetone & Miscible & --- & Miscible & --- \\
    1-Butanal & $\sim$8-9 drops & --- & Floats & --- \\
    2-Butanone & \textless10 drops & --- & Floats & --- \\
    Cyclohexanone & 6 drops & --- & Sinks & --- \\
    Benzaladehyde & \textgreater10 drops & --- & Sinks & --- \\
    Unknown \#6 & 4-5 drops & Boils at 75 & Floats & \\
    \midrule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\theadfont {2,4- Dinitrophenylhydrazone}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\theadfont {Semicarbazones}} \\
    \midrule
    Acetone & Solid & --- & --- & --- \\
    Benzaldehyde & Solid & --- & Slight ppt &--- \\
    Unknown \#6 & Solid &--- & Precipitated & \\
    \midrule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c} {\theadfont Chromic Acid Oxidation} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\theadfont {Tollen's Test}} \\
    \midrule
    Acetone & Positive & --- & Negative & --- \\
    1-Propanal & Negative & --- & Positive & --- \\
    Benzaldehyde & Positive & --- & Positive &  ---\\
    Glucose & \textbf{Skip This Test} & --- & Positive & --- \\
    Unknown \#6 & Positive & & Positve & \\
    \midrule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c} {\theadfont {Iodoform Test}} &  & \\
    \midrule
    Acetone & Precipitated & --- &  & \\
    Ethanol & No Reaction & --- & & \\
    Cyclohexanone & No Reaction &---  & & \\
    Unknown \#6 & No Reaction & --- &  & \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Wow!  I love that much better actually I see what you mean, it is much nicer without the vertical lines.  And sparingly horizontal lines.  Thank YOU so SO MUCH!

Comment: Glad you like it!

Answer (score 3):

I propose two layouts with `tabularx`, with vertical rules and without. I loaded `booktabs, and`cellspace` to give some vertical padding to the rows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{colortbl} \usepackage[svgnames,table,xcdraw,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{booktabs}    
\setlength\cmidrulekern{1em}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\bfseries}Sl|*{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{5}{|Sc|}{Lab Practicum Organic Chemistry II} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|Sc|}{\textbf{Compound}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|} {\textbf{Solubility}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Density}} \\ \hline
                  & \textit{\textbf{Observation}} & \textit{\textbf{Conclusion}} & \textit{\textbf{Observation}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Conclusion}}} \\ \hline
    Acetone & Miscible & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & Miscible & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ \hline
    1-Butanal & $\sim$8-9 drops & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & Floats & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ \hline
    2-Butanone & \textless10 drops & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & Floats & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ \hline
    Cyclohexanone & 6 drops & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & Sinks & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ \hline
    Benzaladehyde & \textgreater10 drops & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & Sinks & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ \hline
    Unknown \#6 & 4-5 drops & Boils at 75 & Floats & \\ \hline
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{2,4- Dinitrophenylhydrazone}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Semicarbazones}} \\ \hline
    Acetone & Solid & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & --- & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ \hline
    Benzaldehyde & Solid & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & Slight ppt & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ \hline
    Unknown \#6 & Solid & & Precipitated & \\ \hline
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|} {\textbf{Chromic Acid Oxidation}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Tollen's Test}} \\ \hline
    Acetone & Positive & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & Negative & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ \hline
    1-Propanal & Negative & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & Positive & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ \hline
    Benzaldehyde & Positive & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & Positive & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ \hline
    Glucose & \cellcolor[HTML] {C0C0C0}\textbf{Skip This Test} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & Positive & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ \hline
    Unknown \#6 & Positive & & Positive & \\ \hline
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|} {\textbf{Iodoform Test}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\ \hline
    Acetone & Precipitated & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\ \hline
    Ethanol & No Reaction & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\ \hline
    Cyclohexanone & No Reaction & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\ \hline
    Unknown \#6 & No Reaction & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}Sl*{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{5}{Sc}{Lab Practicum Organic Chemistry II} \\ \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{1}{Sc}{\textbf{Compound}} & \multicolumn{2}{c} {\textbf{Solubility}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Density}} \\
    \cmidrule{1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-5}
    & \textit{\textbf{Observation}} & \textit{\textbf{Conclusion}} & \textit{\textbf{Observation}} & \textit{\textbf{Conclusion}} \\ \midrule\addlinespace
    Acetone & Miscible & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & Miscible & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ %
    1-Butanal & $\sim$8-9 drops & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & Floats & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\
    2-Butanone & \textless10 drops & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & Floats & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ %
    Cyclohexanone & 6 drops & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & Sinks & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ %
    Benzaladehyde & \textgreater10 drops & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & Sinks & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ %
    Unknown \#6 & 4-5 drops & Boils at 75 & Floats & \\ \midrule\addlinespace[2ex]
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{2,4- Dinitrophenylhydrazone}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Semicarbazones}} \\ %
    \cmidrule(l){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-5}\addlinespace
    Acetone & Solid & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & --- & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ %
    Benzaldehyde & Solid & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & Slight ppt & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ Unknown \#6 & Solid & & Precipitated & \\ \midrule\addlinespace[2ex]%
    & \multicolumn{2}{c} {\textbf{Chromic Acid Oxidation}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Tollen's Test}} \\%
    \cmidrule(l){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-5}\addlinespace
    Acetone & Positive & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & Negative & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ %
    1-Propanal & Negative & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & Positive & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ %
    Benzaldehyde & Positive & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & Positive & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ %
    Glucose & \cellcolor[HTML] {C0C0C0}\textbf{Skip This Test} & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} & Positive & \cellcolor[HTML]{000000} \\ %
    Unknown \#6 & Positive & & Positive & \\ \midrule\addlinespace[2ex]%
    & \multicolumn{2}{c} {\textbf{Iodoform Test}} \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-3}\addlinespace%
    Acetone & Precipitated & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}} \\ %
    Ethanol & No Reaction & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}} \\%
    Cyclohexanone & No Reaction & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{000000}} \\ %
    Unknown \#6 & No Reaction \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image][image]

Comment: (+1) but shouldn't you have a line under `Iodoform Test` in the second example for consistency?

Comment: @cfr: You're right I changed that, and took the opportunity to change cropping of some `\cmidrule`s.

Comment: Normally, no, but I forgot to check it was effective. I did check now!

Comment: I did notice that so I fixed it on my copy. But added the diagonal on the bottom right quadrant